# FILE pointer mysteriously resetting to NULL

Tags: visual-c++, file-io, visual-c++-2008

I'm using visual stduio 2008 c++. And I'm writing windows form application. I declare a FILE* array at the top of Form1.h as a global value

```
const int k = 1; //i need to change k to 2 sometimes. 
FILE* myFiles[k];
```

In From1's constructor, I use a for loop to fopen my files.

```
for(int i = 0; i < k; ++i)
{    
  char filename[100] = "";
  sprintf(filename,"Record/record_%ld_%d.txt",g_recordName,i);
  myFiles[i] = fopen(filename,"w");
}
```

And I set a timer for this form, each tick it will fprintf something into myFiles.
It's fine so far, but if I put something like

```
fprintf(myFiles[0],"%d",1234);
```

into constructor after the for-loop. It works OK this line, but if I'm gonna fprintf anything in timer's tick event, I found that myFiles[0] is already set to NULL!!

In addition, if I `fprintf(myFiles[0],"something")` in the construtor, FILE pointer still won't be null in timer's tick event.

WHY does this happen?! anyone knows why?

Comment: What's the relationship between `myFiles[]` and `g_fout[]`?

Comment: hey sorry! my mistake! it's the same!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple case of buffer overrun. The expression `sprintf(filename,"Record/record_%ld_%d.txt",g_recordName,i);` is most probable the culprit.

Comment: WOW!! Thumbs up, Ajay!! I decrease filename[100] to filename[50]. And it works like a charm! :)

But may I know why and how does that affect myFiles[]? really confused me :(

Comment: Well, it all depends on how compiler puts your variables in memory. You declared an array of `FILE*` which was being placed somewhere. Adjacent to that another array is being placed (filename). The corruption of filename was causing FILE* variable to get zeroed out.  Do a single-step debugging, put both variables into Watch and see when/where it is causing this!

Comment: Thank you very much!! But why is char filename[100] too big? I thought it should be only 400 bytes? And if it happen so easily, I would have lots of problems?

Comment: `char filename[100];` is just 100 bytes, not 400 bytes (just because it is in loop?). You? Many do have lots of problems due to buffer-overrun. Search on the web for buffer overrun, static and dynamic code analysis tools!

Comment: Ah yea, it's 100 bytes. Thank you, I really have learnt something!!

Comment: This is likely *not* a buffer overrun: "Record/record_%ld_%d.txt" can perhaps expand to at most 60 chars, so there's no realistic way it can overrun the 100 chars in the buffer. In any case, buffer overruns happen when a buffer is too small, not when it is too big, so making the buffer smaller would not fix an actual overrun. There may be some other problem here that has disappeared as you moved other code around.

Answer (score 0):

Really thanks to Ajay's help! Yes, this problem (buffer over-run) is caused by sprintf, fprintf. Seems like they are pretty vulnerable. So I changed my code using C++ like stuff - iostream and fstream. Now, it works on me. :) Thank you again.